# In which countries does the body of the dead become property of someone?

Tags: property, comparative-law, death

It's been claimed [on politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/33859/18373) that the body of the dead becomes the property of his family. No country was specified, but is there really a country where this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, Pennsylvania specifically, the court in [Pettigrew v. Pettigrew](https://www.ravellaw.com/opinions/02fa7f5db6683f6f58a6477a390ca680), 207 Pa. 313 says that

> the law rec­ognizes property in a corpse, but property subject to a
>   trust and limited in its rights to such exercise as shall be in
>   con­formity with the duty out of which the rights arise.

[Larson v. Chase](https://casetext.com/case/larson-v-chase), 47 Minn. 307 likewise states

> in this country it is, so far as we know, universally held that those
>   who are entitled to the possession and custody of it for purposes of
>   decent burial have certain legal rights to and in it, which the law
>   recognizes and will protect. Indeed, the mere fact that a person has
>   exclusive rights over a body for the purposes of burial leads
>   necessarily to the conclusion that it is his property in the broadest
>   and most general sense of that term, viz., something over which the
>   law accords him exclusive control.

This is in contrast to the English legal tradition where the church has jurisdiction over a corpse, giving rise to a doctrine that a corpse is not property, citing a dictum from Lord Coke that

> It is to be observed that in every sepulchre that hath a monument two
>   things are to be considered, viz., the monument, and the sepulture or
>   burial of the dead. The burial of the cadaver that is *caro data
>   vermibus* is *nullius in bonis*, and belongs to ecclesiastical
>   cognizance; but as to the monument action is given (as hath been said)
>   at the common law, for defacing thereof.

[This article](https://scholarship.law.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=4512&context=mulr) provides further analysis and case citations, mostly in the US. The topic of body-ownership is the subject of a book-length analysis (ten Have & Welie, *Ownership of the human body*). I think, according to [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3713940/), that under Islamic law, a body (living or dead) is not property, so an advance directive is not an absolute right.

Comment: Looking at the [ToC of that book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792351504) it covers some continental European (French, Dutch, Danish, and probably German) perspectives.